# How to set PhpStorm recognize variable's class

Tags: php, phpstorm, phpdoc

I stacked with a problem in PhpStorm. I have a code:

```
/**
 * $this->data['rows'] My_Class[]
 */
public function countRows(){
    foreach($this->data['rows'] as $row){
        $row->(here i want to get all functions in a class with autocomplete)
    }
}
```

Here I am trying to reach Class functions with PhpStorm autocomplete helper but this doesn't work.

How could I define some variable exact class or type with PHPDoc?

Answer (score 4):

You can type hint `$row` variable directly with `/** @var MyClass $row */` PHPDoc comment:

```
foreach($this->data['rows'] as $row){
    /** @var MyClass $row */
    $row->(here i want to get all functions in a class with autocomplete)
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That is exactly what i want!